# CosmosDB Azure Synapse Link On-Demand SQL Connection not working

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

I've have a CosmosDB instance with a database container that *IS* set up as an Analytical Store.  I've also set up Azure Synapse and I'm importing the database as an External Store.

When I use the following query from the Azure documentation and samples, it returns an error stating Failed to execute query.

`Error: Incorrect syntax near 'Openrowset'.`

```
SELECT  *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    'CosmosDB',
     'account=[account name];database=[database name];key=[key]',
    [Orders]
) 
as q1
```

I'm almost certain I have the account name and database correct.  For the key I'm trying the primary and secondary key from the CosmosDB account's settings.

I need help sorting out what is incorrect, or what is the correct way to query into the CosmosDB's OLAP data when it's been set up for HTAP?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is out of private preview with Synapse SQL serverless.

The query above is missing the region. Here is what it should look like.

```
-- Create view for RetailSales container
CREATE VIEW  RetailSales
AS  
SELECT  *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    'CosmosDB', N'account=<Your Azure Cosmos account name>;
    database=<Your Azure Cosmos database name>;
    region=<Your Azure Cosmos DB Region>;
    key=<Your Azure Cosmos DB key here>',
    RetailSales)
AS q1
```

Comment: It’s enabled in the portal. Doesn’t look like signup is necessary. Plus when in Synapse studio, CosmosDB collections set up for analytics show the new HTAP icon. It seems more of an Azure issue with the SQL driver.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-cosmos-db-analytical-store